# jQuery: How to write a function on click, hold and move?

Tags: jquery

I started learning jQuery just yesterday, and I like it very much.

And now I decided to write a script where I can change the `margin-left` of an image when I click on it, hold the clicking and move the mouse.

Depending on mouse coordinates I must change the image's `margin-left`. Could you give me an idea how I can do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand completely but it sounds like you want the draggable functionality of jQuery UI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQueryUI (http://jqueryui.com/)

Specifically, look at the "Draggable" http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). That will allow you to check where the item is on the screen as well as letting you attach all sorts of other events.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can register events for `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`, and compare the mouse position differences in each of these. Both those event functions get passed an event object as an argument, which has attributes for `clientX` and `clientY`, indicating the position of the mouse at the time of the event.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp